# Loading seperate javascript for different views in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 3 views in my MVC5 App. Say A,B,C and 3 javascript files A.js, B.js  C.js

When appropriate view is loaded, I want appropriate javascript files to get loaded. I do not want all files to get loaded at the start up.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: add the script include in the specific view

Comment: in a view @scripts { <script src="a.js"></script> } and etc.

Comment: If you will ever have multiple JS files per view, create new script bundles in the BundleConfig.cs file (named after the view/purpose) and reference those, one in each view. That way you will get the most efficient caching. I generally recommend using bundles, even for single files, to keep the maintenance in once place.

Answer (score 4):

In ViewA, add the following

```
@scripts {
    <script src="A.js"></script>
}
```

In ViewB, add the following

```
@scripts {
    <script src="B.js"></script>
}
```

and so on...

If you are using a _Layout.cshtml, make sure you have the proper `RenderSection`:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

then in the views itself do this:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="B.js"></script>
}
```